# After docker-compose build the docker-compose up run old not updated containers

Tags: docker, deployment, docker-compose

I use docker-compose and find following problem:

When I change my code and want to rebuild dockers I use

```
docker-compose stop
docker-compose build
```

And then I want to run system by:

```
docker-compose up
```

But no new version of code/containers are run but old ones. What to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use, `docker-compose up --build` or `docker-compose up --build --force-recreate`

Comment: NOT WORKING - I test your solutions and both not working. First thing: I saw if I not run: `docker-compose stop` (before each of your proposition, then I will have multiple running containers in background...). Second thing: the running code was not updated (because docker-composer run old containers - so after build we need to use `docker-compose rm -f` before we run conainers with new code). Last: if we use  `stop` and `rm` and then your version `up --build` then we exchange containers with large gap (build time) of non working service.

Comment: Worked for me though

Comment: May be some thing change in new versions of docker (and `up --build`)?

Answer (score 4):

I have a helper function to nuke everything so that our Continuous blah, cycle can be tested, erm... continuously. Basically it boils down to the following:

To clear containers:

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)
```

To clear images:

```
docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)
```

To clear volumes:

```
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)
```

To clear networks:

```
docker network rm $(docker network ls | tail -n+2 | awk '{if($2 !~ /bridge|none|host/){ print $1 }}')
```

I generally don't require old containers, volumes and networks, so to clear them all I made a bash script which runs to clean up docker environment before each build. And to rebuild the docker using updated code, I use `docker-compose up --build`

Credits to [marcelmfs](https://github.com/marcelmfs) and borrowed from [Source](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/23371)

Comment: Don't delete all your Docker stuff:)

Answer (score 3):

In this case first we should remove old containers (by `rm -f`). So we can deploy new code by:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose stop
docker-compose rm -f
docker-compose up
```

Above sequence is not coincidence - when first instruction build image, the old images running - but when building is finish then old container is stopped, deleted and exchange by new builded one.

I put above commands in handy copy-paste oneliner:

`docker-compose build && docker-compose stop && docker-compose rm -f && docker-compose up`

Comment: Nah, same issue. What actually worked is adding `--build` after `up`

Comment: This worked for me after nothing else did, but I have no idea why - I had no services or containers running when I ran the one liner

Comment: This worked for me after I accidentally downgraded php with a docker override file, and the old images were still running the downgraded version, and --build --force-recreate still repeatedly kept running the old images for some reason.